# How to set counting amount in a slider using input type=number?

Tags: html, css

I have a slider that I am using the following code for

```
<form>
emails: <br>
<div>
<input type="range" id="item1" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
<span class="spanoutput">0</span><br/>
</div>
  Total is: $<span id="endprice">0</span>
</form>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j2bh9stu/1/

What I am trying to figure out is to how to set up the slider to show a price of $2 everytime the slider passes the 10,000 mark on a 1mil scale. Right now I have it outputting $2 for every single number, while I need it to output $2 if the slider is between 0-10k, $4 if its between 10,001 and 20k, ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked your fiddle and modified the js a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/tfqym7cp/2/

main change is here, in the showTotal function:

```
// it's always a good idea to give readable names to variables
let emailCount = $(this).val();
// fist, compute the number of units you want to charge
let units = Math.floor(emailCount/1e4) + 1;
// then it becomes easy to compute the total price
total += parseInt(units * prices[myid]);
```

Cheers!